# Executing the wrapper ksh script at the background which then spans multiple background processes

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, beeline

I have created two ksh shell scripts:

1. wrapper script and
2. db_connect script.

I am spawning multiple background processes from the wrapper script. My problem is when I execute the wrapper script in the background, then the spawned processes are not traceable using "`ps -eaf`" command.

Kindly help: how I can spawn the parent at the background
 and the wrapper intern spawns multiple background processes in ksh scripting.

it turned out to be error when executing beeline command at the background, as soon as the parent is placed on background the beeline background execution in the child process goes to a hung state. here is the sample code. the 2nd one goes to hung state.

beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://host:XXXX/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2" --showHeader=false --verbose =false  --outputformat="csv2" -n XXXXXX 
-p XXXXXX -f test.sql 1> test.out 2> /dev/null

nohup beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://host:XXXX/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2" --showHeader=false --verbose =false  --outputformat="csv2" -n XXXXXX 
-p XXXXXX -f test.sql 1> test.out 2> /dev/null &

Comment: Can you please add the script used to spawn these processes. It's impossible to guess what is wrong without seeing what you did.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do some work on (what is now) your last paragraph.  I'm not at all sure how to interpret it — it isn't clear what you're after. To the extent I can interpret it, you run some processes from a wrapper script in the background, and those processes are not associated with the session (terminal, process group, …) so that `ps` does not list them. It could be that the process you're running is taking steps to disassociate itself from the session (daemonizing itself) and there is nothing you can do. By default, scripts or processes run in background will be listed.

Comment: If you have `connect.sh` containing: `ksh wrapper.sh &` and `wrapper.sh` containing `for i in 1 2 3; do ksh -c "echo $i $(date); sleep 30" & done`, and you run `ksh connect.sh`, you will see messages from the sub-shells and running `ps -f` will show those processes, even though their parent process is PID 1 (the kernel/init process).  Tested on RHEL 6.

Comment: I was researching on my problem. it trrned out to be a problem executing beeline command at the background causes the issue when my parent it self goes in to background. Here is the sample snippet of code. the 2nd one do not work. it goes in to a hung stand and never complete,